# Microsoft Graph filter for onPremisesExtensionAttributes

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Microsoft Graph user with the following property:

```
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
            "extensionAttribute1": "attr1",
            "extensionAttribute2": null,
            "extensionAttribute3": null,
            "extensionAttribute4": null,
             etc.
        },
```

I can't seem to find any documentation or examples on how to filter against this property. I've tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=extensionAttribute1 eq 'attr1'
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1 eq 'attr1'
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/any(x:startswith(x,'attr1'))
```

All of them result in a Bad Request, so clearly something is wrong.

```
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid filter clause",
```

QUESTION: how do you format a filter against onPremisesExtensionAttributes or any other property that contains a list of named properties (e.g. extensionAttribute1...n)?  For a list of strings (e.g. proxyAddresses) you can just do:

```
$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:startswith(x,%27smtp:myemail%27))
```

Comment: Can anyone assist or have any comments on this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but apparently you can't "Contains extensionAttributes 1-15 for the user. Note that the individual extension attributes are **neither selectable nor filterable**. For an onPremisesSyncEnabled user, this set of properties is mastered on-premises and is read-only. For a cloud-only user (where onPremisesSyncEnabled is false), these properties may be set during creation or update."

Comment: wish this had an answer as i want to do the same thing..why didn't they make this a nav property so you could use the / syntax

Comment: Anyone got any solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can now filter on the `onPremisesExtensionAttributes`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1 eq 'attr1'
```

Two important points to note:

1. You need to set the `ConsistencyLevel` HTTP request header to `eventual`. Otherwise you’ll get a `400` status code back with the following message `Property 'extensionAttribute1' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.`
2. You need to include `$count=true` even if you don’t care about the count, otherwise you’ll get a `400` status code back with the following message `Property 'extensionAttribute1' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.`

Source: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-advanced-queries-for-directory-objects-are-now-generally-available/.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  re #1, this is an HTTP header?

Comment: Yes, this is an HTTP request header. I edited the response to clarify this.

Comment: Also, expand won't work, otherwise, you will get this error message: "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'extensionAttribute1' of resource 'User'.